# Ajuda com middleware group

Tags: laravel

Meu arquivo web.php está assim:

```
Route::get('/login', 'AutenticacaoController@login')->name('autenticacao.login');
Route::post('/logar', 'AutenticacaoController@logar')->name('autenticacao.logar');
Route::resource('autenticacao', 'AutenticacaoController');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'MunicipioController@inicio')->name('inicio');
    Route::get('/logout', 'AutenticacaoController@logout')->name('autenticacao.logout');
    Route::resource('municipios', 'MunicipioController');
});
```

Se eu acessar a rota `localhost/login`, consigo acessar de boa, mas se eu acesso `localhost/`, recebo o erro:

> Route [login] not defined.

O que pode estar errado?

A ideia é que, ao acessar `localhost/`, seja redirecionado para `localhost/login`

Comment: Não faltou criar um `middleware` para verificar e redirecionar para essa `\login`? como você fez a sua forma de autenticação, também precisar criar proteção de rotas, a que vem no framework é um exemplo e segue um padrão

Comment: oi @VirgilioNovic eu não sei como fazer. pode me explicar? no tutorial que estou acompanhando, o cara faz semelhante a como estou fazendo.

Comment: Qual tutorial @Italo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é um curso de laravel no site da devmedia. postei a pergunta lá tambem, mas acho que o cara só responde segunda :/

Comment: Então, talvez o cara mescla o que existe no Laravel com o que ele está ensinando. Quando eu faço essa parte, eu monto meu middleware própria e minha própria rota de login ou logout ... ! veja acho que qualquer resposta vai te atrapalhar (acho)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic blz então. mesmo assim valeu pela dica

Comment: Qualquer ajuda pode te atrapalhar no andamento do curso ...  não tem um foco para responder com exatidão ... eu sei uma forma, mas, se o curso o cara utilizar outra ? não vai perder o foco !

Comment: Nas suas configurações de rota, você definiu que é preciso estar logado para acessar `localhost/`, e caso ele não esteja, o Laravel automaticamente redireciona para uma rota com o `name` login por padrão. Se você substituir o `autenticacao.login` por `login`, acredito que redirecionará corretamente.

Comment: realmente funcionou vinicius ^^ valeu

Comment: @ViniciusLourenço se quiser, posta a solução pra ganhar os pontos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa o Middleware padrão do Laravel ele define alguns `name` de rotas padrões. No seu caso, você protegeu a rota `localhost/` mas não definiu o `name` como `login` em alguma outra rota para que o Laravel pudesse redirecionar quando o usuário não estivesse logado.

Basta então trocar de:

```
Route::get('/login', 'AutenticacaoController@login')->name('autenticacao.login');
```

Para:

```
Route::get('/login', 'AutenticacaoController@login')->name('login');
```

E detalhe, o Laravel usa a função `name` para redicionar, então contanto que ela seja `login`, você pode definir como quiser sua rota de login.

Caso queira mudar outras rotas do Auth, veja esse [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-the-loginregister-url-in-laravel-55?page=0).